# speak to vs talk to

Tags: word-choice, difference

My question is about "English Grammar in Use" by Raymond Murphy Unit 36, Exercise 36.5.3.
In this context, which sounds more natural?

The instruction given in the book is to use **wouldn't** + a suitable verb.*

> Paul was very angry about what I'd said and ______ to me for two
> weeks.

I answered "talk to" but the book's answer is "speak to".

I understand "talk to" is generally used in casual situation, such as with friends and family, while "speak to" is more formal.

Could you explain why "speak to" is a better answer from native speakers' perspective?

Comment: When someone is so offended that they refuse to communicate with the person who has upset them, we say _he wouldn't speak to me_ or _he refused to speak to me_. That's just how we say it in English.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understood the key words in this situation are "very angry".